# SQLITE3 Commandline Tool SQL UPDATE Query syntax problem

Tags: update, sqlite, syntax, command-line

I have two databases with identical table structures

Dest.db = main
Source.db = src

the table is called

colorramp

structure of colorramp is

ID | name | xml | favorite

> [image: 1]]

main.colorramp needs to be updated with items from src.colorramp WHERE name=name. (So I don't want to use the ID or PRIMARYKEY)

I have an sql query that looks like the following.

```
UPDATE colorramp 
SET colorramp.xml=(SELECT s1.xml FROM src.colorramp s1 WHERE colorramp.name=s1.name),
SET colorramp.favorite=(SELECT s1.favorite FROM src.colorramp s1 WHERE s1.name=colorramp.name)
```

But i keep getting the error below.

[Error: near ".":syntax error]

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `UPDATE` syntax in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using table names (`SET colorramp.xml=...`). This is not allowed; just use `SET xml=...` instead.

Anyway, the entire statement can be simplified:

```
UPDATE main.colorramp
SET (xml, favorite) = (SELECT xml, favorite
                       FROM src.colorramp
                       WHERE main.colorramp.name = src.colorramp.name);
```